# How do I use .hide and .show without shrinking the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an intro before loading the page content with the code below.

However, every time I click the next and start buttons, the border shrinks down then goes back to normal. How can I get the border to not shrink?

**[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thea0aph/)**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnNext').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrap').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
  });
  $('.start').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').hide();
    $('#contents').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#container {
  border: solid 4px black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#contents {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.1</p>
    <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.2</p>
    <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.3</p>
    <button class="start">start</button>
  </div>
  <p id="contents">asdasdsa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis placeat asperiores veritatis excepturi sunt iste ipsum, aspernatur, nam facilis consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use invisible instead of display none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thea0aph/2/)**.

That happen because the `fadeIn()` will show the element before the end of the `fadeOut()` duration.

To solve this issue you could use `fadeOut()` callback to execute the `fadeIn()` after the end of `fadeOut()` duration, like :

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.wrap').fadeOut(200,function(){
    $(this).next().fadeIn(201)
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnNext').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrap').fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(this).next().fadeIn(201)
    });
  });
  $('.start').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').hide();
    $('#contents').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#container {
  border: solid 4px black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#contents {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.1</p>
    <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.2</p>
    <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quo.3</p>
    <button class="start">start</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="contents">asdasdsa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis placeat asperiores veritatis excepturi sunt iste ipsum, aspernatur, nam facilis consectetur.</p>
```